# How do I connect to ANY database from C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database-connection

Is it possible to build database-agnostic code in C# that will work against either SQL Server or MySQL, depending only on connection string?

I guess I'm looking for something that will throw SQL at a database server, and return a very simplistic set of rows/columns. This database could be...SQL, MySQL, Access, Filemaker, whatever.  It seems that all the databases have their own drivers and objects libraries.  SqlConnection vs. MySqlConnection, etc.

I know about OBDC and the OdbcConnection, which would theoretically do what I want, but I don't want to have to be creating ODBC connections on the server all the time either.

Am I asking for too much here?

Comment: I'm certainly no expert, but I'm pretty sure the only way is to roll your own mediary to interpret/convert the syntax from language to language.

Comment: Many ways to go about it, e.g. Abstract Factory pattern

Comment: SQL is not exactly the same across database though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using an ORM, the answer is "no."  My goal was to send SQL as a string, and get back a simple matrix of rows columns.  This is apparently not possible.

I ended up writing my own object that takes a string and enumeration of the database type, then it uses a switch statement to use various object libraries to connect. I statically compiled the libraries in.

Not the most elegant solution, but it did what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at
NHibernate, LLBLGEN, MyGeneration, NetTiers and other ORMs.

They may allow you to do some sort of abstraction you need. Some are free, some charge.

I personally like NHibernate.

You could do above with interfaces like gleng says:

```
public static IDbDataAdapter GetDataAdapter (Database db)
    {
        switch (db)
        {
            default:
            case "MsSql":
                return new SqlDataAdapter ();
            case "MySql"
                return new MySqlDataAdapter ();
        }
    }

    public static IDbCommand GetCommand (Database db)
    {
        switch (db)
        {
            default:
            case "MsSql":
                return new SqlCommand ();
            case "MySql"
                return new MySqlCommand ();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's called using `interfaces` and `Dependency Injection`. There are many articles and tutorials online that you can find for setting this stuff up.

The idea is you write your own implementation based off an `interface`. You can then swap these out without having to change any of your code by registering the one you want to use in your `IoC` container.

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible by using the classes from **System.Data.OleDb** namespace like OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, ...
if you use only very basic sql statements this should work ... you should also be careful picking the data types for the columns in your table definitions because the types supported will differ for each provider